# Des variantes pour « tout va s’arranger »

Tags: expressions

Je cherche un autre mot ou tournure pour exprimer la chose suivante :
« Tout va s’arranger » dans le sens de « ne t’en fais pas, les circonstances vont s’améliorer plus tard ». Il s’agit ici d’une tournure que l’on prononce pour mettre quelqu’un à l’aise s’il a des soucis.

On peut peut-être dire « tu te débrouilleras » ou « tu te démerderas », mais alors l’écouteur a du pouvoir, c’est voire son boulot de s’en sortir. Si j’entends dire « tu te débrouilleras », je pense qu’on veut dire « pas de soucis, tu n’as pas besoin d’aide, tu sortiras heureusement du pétrin ».

Je veux exprimer que le concours de circonstances rend tout plus vivable. L’écouter y est impuissant. En néerlandais par exemple, on fait allusion à un chat qui sait toujours atterrir sur ses pattes, et survit souvent aux grandes chutes comme ça. On dit donc « tout atterrit sur ses pattes ».

Quelles tournures peuvent également être utilisées ?

Comment: Ton exemple du chat m'a tout de suite fait penser à [retomber sur ses pieds](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=34762) (et parfois sur ses pattes, mais moins courant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parmi les expressions que tu proposes :

- *tu te démerderas*  est vulgaire
- *tu te sortiras du pétrin* est familier

si on veut utiliser une expression impersonnelle neutre autre que *tout va s'arranger* on peut dire :

- *tout va rentrer dans l'ordre*

En nommant le sujet on peut dire :

- *tu t'en sortiras*

Il existe en français l'expression *retomber sur ses pieds*, voire *retomber sur ses pattes* (plus familier), proche de l'expression néerlandaise, mais qui ne s'emploie pas de façon impersonnelle.

Quelques emplois en contexte :

> [C'est toujours plus compliqué pour une femme qui sort d'un licenciement ou de plusieurs grossesses de se réinsérer dans la société, de retomber sur ses pieds](http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2014/06/23/chomage-femmes-seniors-marche-emploi_n_5521100.html?utm_hp_ref=france). (Huffington Post)
>   [Retomber sur ses pieds quand on a été virée!](http://www.coupdepouce.com/bien-dans-ma-tete/travail/retomber-sur-ses-pieds-quand-on-a-ete-viree/a/18084) (un blog)
>   [Retomber sur ses pieds après un défaite électorale.](http://ici.radio-canada.ca/emissions/la_fin_de_semaine_est_a_7h/2013-2014/chronique.asp?idChronique=334683) (Radio Canada)
>   [le patron Renault retombe sur ses pieds](http://blogs.lexpress.fr/media/2013/02/18/epingle-sur-bfm-tv-par-olivier-mazerolle-le-patron-renault-retombe-sur-ses-pieds-sur-bfm-business/) (l'Express)
>    [Je ne m'inquiète pas pour elle. Comme d'habitude, elle va retomber sur ses pieds.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=pgyrhFXjxCQC&pg=PT43&lpg=PT43&dq=%22va%20retomber%20sur%20ses%20pieds%22&source=bl&ots=kteEMdtWNT&sig=1FGBEYvaBfjzw8yX3wLgtKNCDWw&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=DXKyU5S8CaKr0AWdkIHICA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22va%20retomber%20sur%20ses%20pieds%22&f=false) (Roman populaire)
>   [je pense que l'économie va retomber sur ses pieds cet été](http://www.liberation.fr/economie/2001/03/21/je-pensais-que-j-allais-doucement-vers-la-fortune_358581) (journal *Libération*)
>
> [À la mi-août, l'Amiens SC veut retomber sur ses pattes.](http://www.courrier-picard.fr/sports/a-la-mi-aout-l-amiens-sc-veut-retomber-sur-ses-pattes-ia202b0n159877) (Le Courrier Picard.)
>   [DSK va retomber sur ses pattes](http://www.madmoizelle.com/elisabeth-teissier-dsk-65648).(Madmoizelle)

Answer (score 4):

Pourquoi pas la phrase de Scarlet O'Hara:

> Demain est un autre jour...